# Visual Studio 2022 Templates/Casting Spacing (C/C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I have an problem with configuring spacing for C/C++ in Visual Studio 2022.
I cannot find a setting that allows me to add spaces between.

Example, here is default config:

```
std::vector<uintptr_t>
reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
std::vector< uintptr_t >
reinterpret_cast< uintptr_t >
```

I want to add space between the data type. I have only found setting:

Casting in C

```
( double )
```

but that's not what I wanted

Comment: I would recommend to use clang format, since [msvc supports it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/). Advantages: you can have formatting settings in repository, so all developers are using same formatting; almost all IDEs are respecting it, so you are not enforcing on developer specific IDE.

Comment: `SpacesInAngles` does the job, test this here https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ maybe by using this name you will find respective setting in VS.

Comment: Hi,@nof. As they suggested, you may want to consider configuring ClangFormat. You could also refer to the documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-c-cpp-formatting?view=vs-2022).